# How to match chars like %19?

Tags: c#, regex, xml

This is my scenario:
I extract data from a file and I have to control for each line if it matches a regex.
This regex is used in a configuration XML file.
Some of these lines contain the %19 (`&#x19;`) char and I'm not able to match this, because the char `&#x19;` isn't valid in XML.

E.g. If I don't write the regex in XML this one matches my line:

```
(?<Numeri>\d{0,3}(&#x19;){0,1}(\s*?\d\d\d)*,\d{2})
```

With which string I have to replace  in xml?

**Edit**

This is the xml content for the regex

```
(?&lt;Numeri&gt;\d{0,3}(%19){0,1}(\s*?\d\d\d)*,\d{2})
```

Comment: Please post the XML contents. I think you can just replace with `\u0019` (`var xmltxt = xmltxt.Replace("\u0019", "");`).

Comment: Does it mean my suggestion is working for you?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, It works, thank you, add an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `&#x19;` entity in an XML, you need to re-write it, e.g. using `\u` notation: `\u0019`.

In C#, you could replace it like this:

```
var xmltxt = xmltxt.Replace("\u0019", string.Empty);
```